# XSL Copy Child Element to Parent Attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, parent-child, element

I'm just starting to learn about XLS just do modify my XML below. In particular, I would like to copy the value of the `<description>` element and replace it into the `name` attribute of its parent `<game>`.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
   <game name="$100000P" index="" image="">
      <description>$100,000 Pyramid (1988)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Box Office, Inc.</manufacturer>
      <year>1988</year>
      <genre>Strategy</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
   <game name="$takes" index="" image="">
      <description>High Stakes by Dick Francis (1986)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Mindscape, Inc.</manufacturer>
      <year>1986</year>
      <genre>Adventure</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
   <game name="007Licen" index="" image="">
      <description>007 -  Licence to Kill (1989)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Domark Ltd.</manufacturer>
      <year>1989</year>
      <genre>Driving</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
...
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menu>
   <game name="$100,000 Pyramid (1988)" index="" image="">
      <description>$100,000 Pyramid (1988)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Box Office, Inc.</manufacturer>
      <year>1988</year>
      <genre>Strategy</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
   <game name="High Stakes by Dick Francis (1986)" index="" image="">
      <description>High Stakes by Dick Francis (1986)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Mindscape, Inc.</manufacturer>
      <year>1986</year>
      <genre>Adventure</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
   <game name="007 - Licence to Kill (1989)" index="" image="">
      <description>007 -  Licence to Kill (1989)</description>
      <cloneof></cloneof>
      <crc></crc>
      <manufacturer>Domark Ltd.</manufacturer>
      <year>1989</year>
      <genre>Driving</genre>
      <rating></rating>
      <enabled>Yes</enabled>
   </game>
```

I had tried the following XSL but it doesn't seemed to make any changes. Really scratching my heads over right now.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  
    <xsl:template match="game">
        <game name="{description}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </game>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that when you do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

you also copy the original `@name` attribute, overwriting the new `@name` attribute you have just now created.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="game">
    <game>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </game>
</xsl:template>
```

or, if you know all the attributes a `game` will have:

```
<xsl:template match="game">
    <game name="{description}" index="{@index}" image="{@image}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </game>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use both of the suggested xls template and the result is:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <game name="$100,000 Pyramid (1988)" index="" image="">
      $100,000 Pyramid (1988)
      
      
      Box Office, Inc.
      1988
      Strategy
      
      Yes
   </game>
   <game name="High Stakes by Dick Francis (1986)" index="" image="">
      High Stakes by Dick Francis (1986)
      
      
      Mindscape, Inc.
      1986
      Adventure
      
      Yes
   </game>
   <game name="007 -  Licence to Kill (1989)" index="" image="">
      007 -  Licence to Kill (1989)
      
      
      Domark Ltd.
      1989
      Driving
      
      Yes
   </game>

Comment: It now copies the description element into the name attribute of the game element. However all other elements under the game element seemed to just dissapear.

Comment: @D.Sync You need to keep the identity transform template (the first template in your stylesheet) as is. See a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMM

Comment: Ah I must have missed that one out! It now outputted properly! Thanks @michael.hor257k for the help. I'm just starting to learn about XLS and hopefully this will be a good beginning :)